# Lower bounding the expectation of an infimum

Tags: probability, probability-theory, inequality, expectation, supremum-and-infimum

Consider the following sum:

$$
\inf_{u \in \mathbb{S}^{n-1}} \frac{1}{m} \sum_{i=1}^m \left| \langle a_i, u \rangle \right|,
$$
where $\mathbb{S}$ denotes the unit sphere,
$$
\mathbb{S}^{n-1} := \left\{
x \in \mathbb{R}^n: \left\| x \right\|_2 = 1
\right\},
$$

and the $a_i$ satisfy $a_i \sim \mathcal{N}(0, I_n)$ individually but are *not* necessarily independent. (In fact, given a longer vector $g \sim \mathcal{N}(0, I_m)$, every $a_i$ is a shift of $g$ by $i$ positions, cut off at the first $n$ elements. Therefore, the vectors $a_i$ and $a_{i+d}$ are completely independent.)

I'm looking for a **lower** bound on the quantity

$$
\mathbb{E}\left[\inf_{u \in \mathbb{S}^{n-1}} \frac{1}{m} \sum_{i=1}^m \left|
\langle a_i, u \rangle
\right| \right].
$$

A trivial lower bound is $0$ (e.g. by "breaking up" the infimum into individual infima) but I think we should be able to do better given the limited dependence in our sample.